# Non-OK-status: GpuLaunchKernel

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, autoencoder

I trained a simple autoencoder for high resolution images. I can train the network, but not test it (on the same set of data)

A part of the code:

```
image_size_x = 1416
image_size_y = 1440
color_channel = 1

batch_size=10
epochs = 50
initial_epoch = 0
data_augmentation = True

verbose = 1

subtract_pixel_mean = True

number_of_workers = 1

input_shape = [image_size_x, image_size_y, 1]

image = Input(shape=input_shape)

def autoenc(input_img):
    x = Conv2D(kernel_size=(1,1), strides=2, filters =16)(input_img)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)

    x = Conv2D(kernel_size=(2,2), strides=2, filters =32)(x)    
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)    
    x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)

    x = Conv2D(kernel_size=(2,2), strides=2, filters =64)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)   

    x = Conv2D(kernel_size=(3,3), strides=3, filters =128)(x)    
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)    
    x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)

    x = Conv2DTranspose(kernel_size=(3,3), strides=3, filters =128)(x)    
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)    
    x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)

    x = Conv2DTranspose(kernel_size=(2,2), strides=2, filters =64)(x)    
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)    
    x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)

    x = Conv2DTranspose(kernel_size=(2,2), strides=2, filters =32)(x)    
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)    
    x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)

    x = Conv2DTranspose(kernel_size=(1,1), strides=2, filters =16)(x)    
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)    
    x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)

    x = Conv2DTranspose(kernel_size=(1,1), strides=1, filters =1,activation='sigmoid')(x)

    return x

autoencoder = Model(inputs=image, outputs=autoenc(image))    
autoencoder.compile(loss='mse', optimizer = 'adam')    
autoencoder.summary()

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_center=False,
samplewise_center=False,
featurewise_std_normalization=False,
samplewise_std_normalization=False,
zca_whitening=False,
zca_epsilon=1e-06,
rotation_range=0,
width_shift_range=0,
height_shift_range=0,
shear_range=0,
zoom_range=0,
channel_shift_range=0,
fill_mode='nearest',
cval=0,
horizontal_flip=False,
vertical_flip=False,
rescale=1./255,
preprocessing_function=None,
data_format=None,
validation_split=0.2)

image_and_labels=pd.read_csv(csv_path)

train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=image_and_labels,
x_col='images1',
y_col='images1',
class_mode='input',
color_mode='grayscale',
target_size=(image_size_x, image_size_y),
batch_size=batch_size)

autoencoder.fit(train_generator, epochs=epochs, initial_epoch=initial_epoch, verbose=verbose, workers=number_of_workers, callbacks=callbacks)
```

Trained on 1800 images, everything works smoothly. I tried to test it on the SAME train dataset, same batch size..
predict = model.predict(train_generator, steps=None, callbacks=None, max_queue_size=10, workers=1, use_multiprocessing=False, verbose=1)

and it crushes here

2021-11-19 11:47:54.978459: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:369] Loaded cuDNN version 8100
180/180 [==============================] - 61s 318ms/step
2021-11-19 11:48:54.493204: F tensorflow/core/kernels/concat_lib_gpu_impl.cu.cc:151] Non-OK-status: GpuLaunchKernel( concat_fixed_kernel<T, IntType>, config.block_count, config.thread_per_block, 0, gpu_device.stream(), input_ptrs, split_size, static_cast(output->dimension(0)), static_cast(output->dimension(1)), output->data()) status: Internal: invalid configuration argument

Can someone please help me?

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
tensorflow 2.6.0-dev20210614
python 3.8.8
CUDA Version: 11.0
GPU A100-PCIE-40GB